# Did Luke retrieve his Lightsaber from second Death Star?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, luke-skywalker, return-of-the-jedi

At the end of Episode VI: ROTJ, Luke defiantly "hurls away" his lightsaber  - according to both screenplay and novelization - before declaring "I am a Jedi, as my father was before me".

I have just re-watched the scene, and can't see anywhere where that lightsaber fell in any of the shots, nor do I see a single shot where Luke would pick up his lightsaber after the Emperor died.

Is there any canon information on what happened to that lightsaber? Did he retrieve it? Did he just build a new one and this one blew up together with Death Star 2?

NOTE: *We know for sure that Vader's fell to the chasm below the walkway where Luke fought him, from both the screenplay and novelization. Since Luke's isn't mentioned to have fallen down, it may be presumed possible that it didn't.*

Comment: Shouldn't that be '*Episode VI: RotJ*'? Or did the title get changed to something else, instead of '*Return of the Jedi*'? (I'm assuming it's a typo from '*Episode III: Revenge of the Sith*')

Comment: @DavidThomas - freudian slip. I want the Sith to win, subconsciously :)

Comment: @DavidThomas - The [original film poster](http://i.imgur.com/69yg0.jpg)

Comment: Related: [Was Luke's lightsaber recovered after the final battle with Vader?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62742/49)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Yes, he did.**
We see it in the "celebration on Endor" scene a few minutes later, just after he's cremated his father.

[image]

Under the circumstances, we can assume that when he "hurled it aside", it simply rolled under the staircase behind the Emperor

[image]

[image]

**Update**: According to the factbook "[Inside the Worlds of Star Wars Trilogy: The Ultimate Guide to the Incredible Locations of Episodes IV, V, and VI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756603072)", the saber was almost exactly where I guessed it was...

[image]

Comment: Is it me or Luke looks high or drunk here?

Comment: @DVK - He certainly looks pleased with himself.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RFYoZ7H67A - at about 4:40 you can clearly hear the lightsaber landing

Comment: @DVK I'm not sure, whether Luke looks high, but The Emperor certainly looks a bit surprised! :>

Comment: I think George Lucas needed to add a short scene with Luke and Darth Vader on hands and knees looking for his lightsaber under the stairs. ;)

Comment: @RobertF - Or one where Luke struck at the emperor first and the emperor was just defending himself with the force lightning?

Comment: @Richard I can just imagine this in the deleted scenes, only it's a blooper where Luke accidentally attacks the emperor first, and then Mark Hamil and Ian McDiarmid crack up laughing.

Answer (score -1):

I would guess he retrieved it before helping his father to the shuttle bay. He was a rebel on a death star, he still would have been a target by imperial soldiers.

Comment: This would be a good reason...but is there evidence that he did this?

Comment: yeah at the end when he has the lightsaber in the pic

Answer (score -2):

He most certainly did not have it when he dragged Vader across the hangar. It's either a tiny plot hole, it was in his prison wallet, or he had decided earlier that it made no sense to build one when he could build two for twice the price.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Since it's definitely the case that Luke has his lightsaber when he gets back to the forest moon, it follows that he _must_ have retrieved it, no?  Can you show any shots as he carries Vader to the shuttle where he definitely doesn't have it?